# How does this arrow function work in my special case passing it through Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mapstatetoprops

I learn JavaScript and React Redux and have this question:.

Let's say I have this Redux `dispatch`:

```
dispatch(setLogMessage( () =>{"Connecting to env1", 12340, "connecting"}));
```

and the reducer is here for the above `setLogMessage` is this:

```
   const initialState = {
     log: "",
   };

    case booksActionTypes.LOG_MESSAGE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        log: action.payload,
      };
    }
```

And in the `mapStateToProps` it looks like this:

```
  const [theLog, addLog] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
        if (props.log !== "") {
          addLog([...theLog, createData(props.log)]);
        }
      }, [props.log]);
    
      function createData(message, timestamp, type) {
        console.log('s');
        return { message, timestamp, type };
      }
```

The problem is I play around and wanted to learn the arrow functions in this context and wanted to have the above `props.log`, to be a function to resolve the above `() =>{"Connecting to env1", 12340, "connecting"})` and pass it to `function createData(..`.
Hope you understand my question!

Comment: Can you add the actual `setLogMessage` action creator?

Comment: `() =>{"Connecting to env1", 12340, "connecting"}` are you expecting this to return an object??

Comment: Also, what midleware are you using?

Comment: @BrianThompson It looks like this `export const setLogMessage = (log) => ({
  type: booksActionTypes.LOG_MESSAGE,
  payload: log,
});`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I don't add any middleware in this setup Redux, like Saga or else

Comment: What is the current behavior? Where is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: @BrianThompson Thanks, it looks like this putting a [breakpoint](https://snipboard.io/LEmc2f.jpg) . The `createData(message, timestamp, type)` is called ok but the, `message` attribute is the only one populated with function from the dispatche  . ` timestamp, type`  is `undefined`

Comment: Ok, so you have two problems. You are not calling `props.log`, only passing it as a reference. Problem two is that your function passed to `setLogMessage` does not return anything.

Comment: @BrianThompson feels like your on to something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Immediately returning objects from arrow functions can be syntactically confusing...

The `{` appears to be opening a new object, but in reality it is opening up a function body.

To resolve this, wrap the object in parenthesis (notice the object property names as well):

```js
() => ({ message: "Connecting to env1", timestamp: 12340, type: "connecting"})
```

The second problem is that you are never calling this function.

`props.log` holds that function reference, so to get its values as parameters to `createData` you need to call it (and pass the individual values).

```js
const values = props.log();
createData(values.message, values.timestamp, values.type);
```

#### Summary

1. Implicit returns require wrapping parenthesis when returning an object.
2. Objects **must** contain a property name, not just a value (that's what arrays are for)
3. Functions must be called, not just passed as props.

Comment: Omg I learn so much, It's [working](https://snipboard.io/YW3d0y.jpg)..